# couchbase xdcr replication with view

Tags: view, couchbase, database-replication

i have a question.

I have couchbase installed in this situation:

2 cluster with:
cluster 1:
192.168.1.91
192.168.1.92
192.168.1.93

and cluster 2:
192.168.1.94
192.168.1.95
192.168.1.96

i want to set up replication...so i have created a bucket (test) with 2 replicas, so...
i think that data is replicated in cluster 1... and in cluster 2..

i have set 2 xdcr...
one in cluster 1 to cluster 2 and another one
in cluster 2 to cluster 1....

and seem working but i don't understand some thinks...
1) data is replicated from cluster 1 to cluster 2... but there is a way to replicated also the views?..
2) i have seen another think... in bucket test i have for example 1000 record.
so.. more or less 300 for node.
if a node go down i thoght that i see anywhere 1000 record (for this reason i need replication and i set 2 replicas for bucket) but instead i see only 600 record of my bucket test,why this?

thanks a lot to anyone..

Answer (score 0):

1) views aren't replicated. What you should do is create the same views on both sides of the cluster and they will be updated as data is replicated between your clusters.

2) My guess is that when your node crashes you are not actually failing it over. This needs to be done in order to active the replicas on the other nodes.